# Gnuplot: Axis format

Tags: gnuplot

I have a question about the format of the axis in gnuplot.

I am obtaining a plot that looks like this

[image].

But I want the axis formats to match, I have so far used

"set format x '%.0t*10^{%.0S}'"

to obtain

[image].

The question is if there is any way of changing the * to a x so the y and x axis match. I have read that {/Symbol \264} should produce a x for me, but this does not seem to work on my system as it produces some other symbol.

Comment: With gnuplot version 5 simply use `set format '%h'` (which is also the default) to get proper multiplication signs for both axes

Comment: Thank you! This gives me what I want. Don't get why it changes it from default in the first place

Comment: I don't know, maybe you have some respective settings in your script, or in a startup file, ...